# Print with category in java using method overriding in java

Tags: java, arrays, methods, overriding

how to print Junior, Intermediate,Seniour as string as per age,and must generate roll number and these input must b generated from the user. Ex: junior name:Rahul age:22, roll:1000 intermediate name:prem age:40, roll:1001 senior name: Vamsi age:60, rollno:1002

```
String name;
static int age;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int size = 3;
    DB[] studs = new DB[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        studs[i] = readStudent(i);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i <studs.length; i++) {
        if(age <=30) {
            System.out.println( studs[i]);
        }else if(age <=40) {
            System.out.println("Intermidiate" +" "+studs[i]);
        }else {
            System.out.println("Seniour" +" "+studs[i]);
        }
    }
}


static DB readStudent(int i) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter your name:");
    String name = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter your age:");
    int age = sc.nextInt();
    DB studs = new DB(name, age);
    return studs;
}

}

class juniourStudent extends Student {
    String rollno = "juniour";
    static int juniourcount = 1000;

    juniourStudent(String name, int age) {
        rollno = "juniour" + juniourcount++;
    }
}

class intermidiateStudent extends Student {
    String rollno = "intermidiate";
    static int intermidiatecount = 1000;

    intermidiateStudent(String name, int age) {
        rollno = "intermidiate" + intermidiatecount++;
    }
}

class seniourStudent extends Student {
    String rollno = " seniour";
    static int seniourcount = 1000;

    seniourStudent(String name, int age) {
        rollno = "seniour" + seniourcount++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a problem with your code? What is your question?

Comment: I wan to get output like  Ex: junior name:Rahul age:22, roll:1000 intermediate name:prem age:40, roll:1001 senior name: Vamsi age:60, rollno:1002
if the student name is below 20 then the student should Coe under junior like that for all 3 but my output is only displaying the name, age of the student

Comment: There's a lot of issues in your code ...Can you post the entire code

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1R_dgHT4WC3axGfm_vGMMFtKpsbWbbvEP?usp=sharing. Here is the file I can't able to upload the code

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few issues with your code.

1. Your class structure is counter-intuitive to what you are trying to do. Based on the example output, it seems that you want the rollNo to increase every time a student is made. It also seems to be redundant to create separate classes when the only thing that differs between them is the prefix (like junior, senior, intermediate, etc.). Instead of making multiple classes, why not add an instance variable to your student class. (Also import Scanner so we can use it later for user input, and ArrayList to store the student data) For Example:

   ```
   import java.util.Scanner;
   import java.util.ArrayList;
   public class Student {
       String name;
       String studentType;
       int age;
       int rollno;
       static int schoolRollno = 1000;
   ```
2. Next you should make a proper constructor for your student class consisting of a String name and an int age, and assigning them to the instance variables we declared earlier. We will assign the studentType variable based upon their age, and we will obtain the students rollno from the static variable. We must increment the static variable so the next student will have a different roll number. (You can change the age comparisons to whatever number you need, but these numbers are what I pieced together from your code)

   ```
   public Student(String name, int age) {
       this.name = name;
       if(age <= 30) {
           this.studentType = "Junior";
       }
       else if(age <= 40)  {
           this.studentType = "Intermediate";
       }
       else {
           this.studentType = "Senior";
       }
       this.age = age;
       this.rollno = schoolRollno;
       schoolRollno++;
   }
   ```
3. The last thing we need to do before we work on our main function is to write a toString() method for our student class. Based upon the output, you might want a method like this:

   ```
   @Override
   public String toString() {
       return studentType + " name: " + name + " age: " + age + ", roll: " + rollno;
   }
   ```
4. Now we can take a look at the `public static void main(String args[])` function. We have a few things we need to do here. Since it appears we do not know the number of students we are going to be adding, we should use an ArrayList. We should also instantiate our scanner here as well:

   ```
   ArrayList<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();
   Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
   ```
5. Now we should create a while loop that allows the user to continue inputting students and wish to stop. Personally, I'm a fan of the do/while loop, so I'll do it that way. We'll need to declare our variable outside of the loop so that we can use it as a conditional for the loop.

   ```
   boolean done = false;
   do {
       //(inner loop code here)
   } while(!done);
   //end loop code
   ```
6. Now for the inner loop code. We need to obtain a String (name) from the user and an int (age). Once we obtain the inputs, we want to construct a Student object and add it to our ArrayList. Then, after all that, we want to see if the user wants to input another student (by changing the value of our boolean we used when declaring the first do/while loop according to the user's input). We can do all this using scanner like so:

   ```
   System.out.println("Enter name:");
   String name = scan.nextLine();
   System.out.println("Enter age:");
   int age = scan.nextInt();
   //we use scan.nextLine() here because scan.nextInt() does not read to the end of the line
   scan.nextLine();
   Student s = new Student(name, age);
   students.add(s);
   boolean validInput = true;
   do {
       validInput = true;
       System.out.println("Continue? (y/n)");
       String input = scan.nextLine();
       if(input.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
           done = false;
       }
       else if(input.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {
           done = true;
       }
       else {
           validInput = false;
       }
    } while(!validInput);
   ```
7. Finally, we want to print the students once we are done. We can print all the students in our ArrayList easily using a for-each loop. (This goes at the end of our `main(String args[])` method)

   ```
   for(Student s: students) {
       System.out.println(s.toString());
   }
   ```

TL;DR:

1. Combine your classes into one student class
2. Fix the constructor
3. Add a `toString()` method
4. Use an ArrayList to store the students b/c we don't know the number. (DB isn't a class in java, and an array is counter-intuitive when you don't know what size you'll need)
5. Create a loop that the user can break out of when they wish to
6. Obtain user input for the name and age, and use this to construct a student object and add it to the ArrayList
7. Print out all the students in the ArrayList after the loop